# dividing the text files in block

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to read a text file and divide it into blocks. Below is the pattern of input text file:

```
DEFINE JOBSET ID=jobset_def FAILCOND=(1,9999)

DEFINE JOB ID=(jobset_def,job1_def,0010) 
DESCRIPTION='Checks the data file against the token file'
DEFINE JOBPARM ID=(jobset_def,job1_def,0010) SUBFILE=/scripts/chk_file.ksh SUBUSER=pbods SUBPASS=*PASSWORD*
PARM1='parm1'
PARM2='parm2.dat'

DEFINE JOB ID=(jobset_def,job2_def,0030)  
DEFINE JOBPARM ID=(jobset_def,job2_def,0030)
SUBFILE='exec_sess_instance.ksh' SUBUSER=pbods SUBPASS=*PASSWORD*
PARM1='parm1'
PARM2='parm2'
.......
```

I want to divide the text file into smaller chunks and store it into HashMap. Each value of HashMap will be a Job defination i.e. from **DEFINE JOB ID** to next **DEFINE JOB ID**. Below is my code:

```
public class UpdateJobs {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("H:/Project_Documents/ALM/ns_pbds_gwm_uscore_account_omx.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    HashMap <Integer, StringBuffer> jobdef= new HashMap <Integer, StringBuffer>();
    int i=1;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = jobdef.keySet().iterator();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("DEFINE JOB ID")){
            jobdef.put(i, stringBuffer);
            i++;
            stringBuffer.setLength(0);
        }
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        //System.out.println("Line is" +line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
    fileReader.close();
    while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){
          Integer key = keySetIterator.next();
          System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + jobdef.get(key));
            }           
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is I am not getting any output. The code runs without any error but the problem is every time it enters into the first while loop it makes a entry in the hashmap and on the next entry it overwrites the previous entry and make a new entry i.e.

```
Loop1: 
key, value
1, DEFINE JOBSET ID=jobset_def FAILCOND=(1,9999)

DEFINE JOB ID=(jobset_def,job1_def,0010) 
DESCRIPTION='Checks the data file against the token file'
DEFINE JOBPARM ID=(jobset_def,job1_def,0010) SUBFILE=/scripts/chk_file.ksh SUBUSER=pbods SUBPASS=*PASSWORD*
PARM1='parm1'
PARM2='parm2.dat'

Loop2:
key, value
1,DEFINE JOB ID=(jobset_def,job2_def,0030)  
DEFINE JOBPARM ID=(jobset_def,job2_def,0030)
SUBFILE='exec_sess_instance.ksh' SUBUSER=pbods SUBPASS=*PASSWORD*
PARM1='parm1'
PARM2='parm2'

2,DEFINE JOB ID=(jobset_def,job2_def,0030)  
DEFINE JOBPARM ID=(jobset_def,job2_def,0030)
SUBFILE='exec_sess_instance.ksh' SUBUSER=pbods SUBPASS=*PASSWORD*
PARM1='parm1'
PARM2='parm2'
....
```

and at the end of the loop it prints nothing in the second while loop i.e. it deletes all the entries in the HashMap.

I am unable to debug it and stuck on this from past 2 days. Help will be appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you put the `StringBuffer` object itself into the `HashMap` as a value, and since it's an `Object`, the code points to the same area in memory whenever and wherever you access it. This means that when you put `stringBuffer` into the `HashMap` and change its content afterwards, the content inside the `HashMap` is changed as well.

A quick fix would be to instantiate a `new StringBuffer()` object at each time you read a "DEFINE JOB ID" in your line.

That means changing this:

```
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = jobdef.keySet().iterator();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("DEFINE JOB ID")){
            jobdef.put(i, stringBuffer);
            i++;
            stringBuffer.setLength(0);
        }
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        //System.out.println("Line is" +line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
```

To this:

```
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = jobdef.keySet().iterator();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("DEFINE JOB ID")){
            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            jobdef.put(i, stringBuffer);
            i++;
            stringBuffer.setLength(0);
        }
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        //System.out.println("Line is" +line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The code that you provided is giving null point exception at `stringBuffer.append(line)`

Comment: I changed the code. The NullPointerException was caused because the text file does not start with "DEFINE JOB ID", making the code try to append to a StringBuffer that hasn'e been instantiated yet.

Comment: Thanks @thehuywhodreams for your comment. The changed code is also not working however the logic/concept you shared helped me to make the changes and now I have the working code.

           `if (line.contains("DEFINE JOB ID")){
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(stringBuffer);
                 jobdef.put(i, sb);
                 i++;
                 stringBuffer.setLength(0);
             }`